# WPF WebBrowser events for HTTP errors?

Tags: wpf, events, browser, webbrowser-control

I have a WPF application and I'm using the WebBrowser control to display some content from a public website.

Sometimes in weird edge cases when the network connectivity is flakey, the web browser will show the "This program cannot display the webpage" error page. Is there some way to listen to the WebBrowser to detect when this occurs, so I can load a placeholder?

Comment: Another solution is available here: [enter link description here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14748621/2381779

Answer (score 2):

You could try using the [`NavigationService`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.frame.aspx) from [`System.Windows.Controls.Frame`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.frame.aspx) as indicated in this [MSDN forum post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wpf/thread/856608db-48ba-4492-bff1-3721618ff3ae). The `WebResponse` will always be null for the `WebBrowser` control in WPF (*as described in the post*).

Comment: That tells us how to get the WebResponse, but how do we check for page load failure with the response?

Comment: I created an example of this as an answer to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29979898/271588) question.

Answer (score 0):

In the `Navigated` event arguments, you can access the `WebResponse`, so you can access the HTTP response code.

Comment: My app only calls refresh() on my browser control and it seems the Navigated event never gets fired after the first initialization. Does refresh() not have an event I can listen to?

Comment: Apparently not... It's weird that Refresh doesn't trigger Navigated, it looks like a bug

Comment: I'm having a similar issue where in I'm not able to access the HTTP headers available in WebResponse.  
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1956590/how-to-get-the-response-headers-while-the-user-navigates-from-page-to-page

Comment: `WebResponse` is always null