# How to get the response headers while the user navigates from page to page?

Tags: wpf, browser

I have a WPF webbrowser control which navigates the user to a registration site. After the user registers, a collection of headers are sent back alongwith the "finished registration" page.
I have tried the Navigated event, and tried accessing WebResponse property in the event arguments but it's always null.
Is there any other way to access the headers sent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After quite a lot of reading, I figured out that WPF web browser actually wraps around the WinForm web browser which inturn wraps around a COM dll (which is even used by Internet Explorer).

Now this COM dll provides a lot of interfaces which are not exposed by any of the wrapper controls. So those who need more control need to implement these interfaces.

I found a browser which implements a lot of these interfaces and neatly provides a lot functionality. Used it and it's working fine. http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/csEXWB.aspx

It talks about implemnting a PassthroughAPP package to get the response headers.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you can access headers like that, best thing to do is, either use Hidden Fields of the form or you can pass on your cookie ASP.NET_SessionID from your finished page to your WPF app, and inside WPF app you can make custom request to your url with same ASP.NET_SessionID cookie where you will continue same session and you will be able to query responses you desire throught WebResponse.